# Looping to get result in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("P2").Formula = "=IF(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B2=B2)*($K$2:$K2=K2)),3)=1,1,0)"
    .Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("P2:P" & lastRow)
    .Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Value = .Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Value
    .Range("F2").Formula = "=IF"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I want to achieve is to use the existing code to continue to add on to get the value in **Column F** to get the quantity.

If the quantity is < 36, then 1 point in "point" column;

if the quantity is 36 - 45, then 2 points in "point" column;

if the quantity is more then 46, then 3 points in the "point" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Range("P2:P" & lr)
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)>1, 0, IF(F2<36, 1, IF(F2<46, 2, 3)))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is able to work. However, I need to remain what I had in my previous codes. But I just need the additional function to change the points on what you did. What my previous codes are saying is that, if there are repetitive postal code the point would be (1,0,0). Then now I need to implement new things such that it would track on the quantity. (Which is what I am asking for help)

Comment: Can you help me please? @paulbica

Comment: I made an update to the formula, that will determine the points based on the uniqueness of the postal code

Comment: I just found a bug. The code does not compare with the name column. It should only show 1,0 when both the name are the same. 
For example: 3 same postal codes and 3 same name the score should be 1,0,0 . If 3 same postal codes and 3 different name the score should be 1,1,1

Answer (score 0):

just add the below lines before `End with` in your code

```
.Range("Q2").Formula = "=IF(AND(F2<36,F2>0),1,IF(AND(F2>=36,F2<=45),2,IF(F2>46,3,""Zero or Beyong 46"")))"
.Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow)
.Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Value = .Range("Q2:Q" & lastRow).Value
```

Comment: It will override what I had above.. I want my result to be 1,0,0 if there is duplicate. After that I want the result to change according to the quantity again.